# How do you build an IntelliJ project from the command line?

Tags: command-line, build, intellij-idea

I'm looking for the best way to build an IntelliJ project from command line. This is usually needed while compiling IntelliJ project on a build server.

Comment: Use [tag:maven] or any other build tool from the beginning and only import it to IntelliJ. What if your teammates are not using IntelliJ?

Comment: I've tried both Maven import and export and it has never worked well. It seems it isn't a trivial problem to convert between project file formats. In this project my teammates are using IntelliJ.

Comment: You are probably talking about `mvn idea:idea` approach. I don't like it either. But have you simply tried importing the project from IntelliJ (New Project -> Import project from external model -> Maven)? It works quite good, even on multi-module projects.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both (but some time ago).

Comment: Creating a Maven project via `mvn archetype:generate` and then just opening the project via selecting the POM file has worked for me just fine using IDEA 11.  Try it again.

Comment: I very much prefer native IntelliJ to writing Maven poms - even if it works.

Comment: @Arne Evertsson: Have you found any way to solve the problem? I have the same problem as yours.

Comment: I haven't really looked. It's on my todo list to set up TeamCity which would seem to solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [TeamCity](https://jetbrains.com/teamcity) build server, developed by JetBrains. It has a full-functional free edition and has a dedicated IntelliJ IDEA build runner, which can build artifacts from your IDEA project and run configurations.

TeamCity uses JPS command line runner, which is a part of IntelliJ IDEA community edition [source base](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/jps).

Answer (score 3):

In build menu is Generate Ant Build ... Idea will generate build.xml file. You have to intall Ant add it to PATH and then you can call in project directory command ant.

Comment: Not a good idea. The artifact prepared by ant may differ from the one created by Maven, oops !!!

Comment: In addition, you developers have to keep the ant file updated all the time, otherwise the build will be broken. !!!

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a small bash script that creates the necessary files you'd need to [create an IntelliJ web project from the commandline](https://github.com/activedecay/ij-proj-cli). All I did was create a project using the IntelliJ GUI. After inspecting the files, I set a variable for each time the project directory name was used in the files that were created **(.idea/module.xml**, and **project.iml**, etc.) The script creates the same files and .idea/ folder that would have been created if you used the GUI.